# CURL Alternative

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Is there a CURL alternative ,so that I am able to set cookies returned in the response from server.And I should be also able to send that cookies further to the url..I know this is possible with CURL.But I need an alternative way .Can I do it  using

```
stream_context_create()
```

and
`flie_get_contents()`
..In my case I need to submit some data using HTTP POST method.If the data is correct the server will set a cookie and I need to use this cookie for further accesss to the server.How can this be done without CURL??

Comment: perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/book.http.php can help you

Comment: Yes, stream contexts can do what you want. However you're going to need to be a lot more specific with your questions. You should probably experiment with stream contexts for a bit, and then come back when you're stumped.

Comment: Actually I experimented with it..Sending data using POST method is successfull..But setting cookie..i'm not successsfull in that..:(

Comment: @JinuJD: What's your problem with the cookies? PHP Manual has cookie example: http://php.net/stream_context_create#example-3880